# Error in make command while installing SAPRFC

Tags: php, installation, makefile, saprfc

I am trying to install SAPRFC on my linux  4.0.4-x86_64 (ubuntu14) machine.

Steps done so far

- Downloaded rfcsdk 6.40 and uploaded in /usr/local/rfcsdk
- Extracted saprfc-1.4.1 in my root directory
- Executed following command

  ```
  - phpize
  - ./configure
  - make
  ```

  after running make command i am getting following error

  ```
  -/root/saprfc-1.4.1/saprfc.c: In function ‘zif_saprfc_get_ticket’:
   /root/saprfc-1.4.1/saprfc.c:2485:5: warning: ‘zend_get_parameters_ex’   is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_API.h:241) [-Wdeprecated-declarations] 
   if (ZEND_NUM_ARGS() != 1 || zend_get_parameters_ex(1, &rfc) == FAILURE){
    ^
    make: *** [saprfc.lo] Error 1
  ```

warning: ‘zend_get_parameters_ex’   is deprecated

make: *** [saprfc.lo] Error 1

Can anyone help me out in solving this issue.

Comment: Add more context, This warning does not seam to be the cause of the failure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify file saprfc.c. Replace *function_entry* with ***zend***_function_entry on line 47.